# Setting Precision in float

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal

I have the following code

```
    float f = 125.0f;
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println(form.format(f));
```

form.format(f) is returning string, but i need it to be float.
I want to set precision for the data which i am printing without changing the datatype i.e. float, How can i do that.

Comment: If you care about decimal digit precision inside your calculations, rather than just for display, reconsider using `float`. Most two decimal place numbers are not exactly representable. `BigDecimal` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`float` doesn't have a precision in terms of printing. It is just a value.

What you can do is round the result so that when it is printed it has no more than 2 decimal places.

```
public static float round2(float f) {
    final float factor = 1e2f;
    if (f < Integer.MIN_VALUE/factor || f > Integer.MAX_VALUE/factor)
       return f;
    return Math.round(f * factor) / factor;
}
```

Note: `float` has a very poor precision and you would be much better off using `double` or considering `BigDecimal` which allows you to control the number of decimal places it would print.

To round `double` you can use

```
public static double round2(double f) {
    final double factor = 1e2;
    if (f < Long.MIN_VALUE/factor || f > Long.MAX_VALUE/factor)
       return f;
    return Math.round(f * factor) / factor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BigDecimal` for that (see also [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html))

```
float f = 125.0f;
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(f).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(value.floatValue());
```

Comment: I would use an example which would be rounded +1